# sudo apt update problem ubuntu 23.04

Tags: apt, 23.04

I am new to Linux and when I try to run `sudo apt update`, I get some errors I'd like to get help with

```
    sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You mention 23.04 which is *lunar*, however your messages all say *kinetic* which is Ubuntu 22.10. Your question & paste do not match.